# Standard ML: Naming datatypes of function arguments possible?

Tags: sml, standards, ml

I'm new to ML and with to have a function that receives a special pre-defined datatype, and able to reference to its entire argument datatype, rather its components.

Here's a stupid example:

```
datatype frame = Frame of string list * string list 

(* Type: fn : string * frame -> frame *)
val lookup_variable_value_in_frame = 
  fn (string(var), Frame(variables, values)) =>     
    ... 
    Frame(variables, values) 
    ... ;
```

1) I want to return the given frame. Must I build another `Frame` ?

2) I wish to pass the given frame to another function, must I provide a new `Frame(variables, values)` again ?

I wish I could write somthing like this:

```
val lookup_variable_value_in_frame = 
     fn (string(var), frame : Frame(variables, values)) =>  ...
```

then I'll be able to use the frame or its components .

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your datatype has already has a name, which is `frame`. You don't have to build another `frame` for returning or passing to another function. The first option is using explicit type annotation:

```
(* Type: fn : string * frame -> frame *)
val lookup_variable_value_in_frame = 
  fn (var: string, f: frame) =>     
    ... 
    f 
    ... ;
```

This option is not common, it should used only when you need types less generic than they are inferred by the type checker. Another option is using `as` keyword to make another binding to the value:

```
val lookup_variable_value_in_frame = 
     fn (var, f as Frame(variables, values)) =>  
         ...(* using f, variables or values here *)
```

Note that there is no such thing like `string(var)` in SML, either use `var` or `var: string` for explicit type annotation.